# SSRS - Sort by number part of string

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I have an SSRS report that will be used in Dynamics 365 so I can't use SQL in the dataset to help here.

I have a product/version code column that is string mixing letters and numbers. For example:

FF8,
FF9,
FF10,
FFA

These are going in to a column header and form a column group which is also sorted by the code. The standard alphabetical sorting is giving this order:

FF10 - FF8 - FF9 - FFA

I'm happy to use a substring in my sort expression to remove a preceding product code but I would like the numbers in ascending numerical format followed by text versions alphabetically:

FF8 - FF9 - FF10 - FFA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a calculated column to your dataset that strips the non-numeric characters and converts to a number. This would make it easier to sort

A formula like this might help

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!productcode.Value, "[^0-9]", "")
```

The `^` symbol means "not" so this Regex expression will remove all characters that are not in the range of 0 to 9 (i.e. all non-numeric characters)

According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2600639/custom-code-that-is-allowed-for-use-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-online-f), `Regex.Replace` should be supported in CRM's sandboxed reports

Comment: Thanks, I've expanded on this a bit by replacing non-numberic characters with a 0 instead of blank then converting to an int (blank was giving an error). I then change 0 to 999 to push alphabetical codes to the back. In my column group I sort by this second calculated field then by original product code

Answer (score 1):

You also could use expression like below in Sort

[image]

=switch(Fields!name.Value="FF10",3,Fields!name.Value="FF9",2,Fields!name.Value="FF8",1,Fields!name.Value="FFA",4)

Zoe

Comment: Thanks for the idea and one to bear in mind though it's restrictive if new products are added. The regex solution should handle this