# SSRS Report Custom Sorting rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

[I have report which shows data of site and some values of each calender week. There is 1 row which contains values for whole group. I want group row on top and other sites alphabetically. I tried to sort but group row does not come on top. I cannot manually sort it 1 by 1 as sites column is random as sites may vary every week, is it possible somehow to have GROUP row on top always and other sites below?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTmwx.jpg)

[I want sorting like given in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzXwA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to "add total - before" to row groups.

Answer (score 0):

You could right click "Details" in Row Group to "add total->before". In addition, if you want to sort column, you also could refer to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0295a21f-63c2-420f-87b0-d9f301817b27/ssrs-2008-r2-sort-on-a-grouping?forum=sqlreportingservices)
 and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856183/ssrs-sort-by-number-part-of-string/53864648#53864648)  for details.

Zoe